# MasterCard Gateway - Order of Operations

Tags: api, bank, mastercard

although I can while reading the documentation understand what the different operations do, I'm rather unfamiliarized with the all "Bank API" enviroment.

My question:

After the Authentication Payerm what should be the order of operations?

TIA,

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Although I couldn't find the "order of operations", I started using their integrated environment, leaving all of the authentication an most of the processing to them.

Thanks anyway,

Comment: Hi, hope all is well. I am currently using firebase as my backend and im starting the integration process with MPGS, will i be able to accomplish it with firebase or will i be to have a nodeJS express server to do that for me?